# A logic to pick the values in NUM to fill for DENOM from 2 columns

Tags: sas

Before

```
_Name_  NUM
_O_NO_VAR1  2
_O_NO_VAR2  4
_O_NO_VAR3  3
_O_NO_VAR4  5
_O_NO_VAR5  6
_O_NO_VAR6  4
_O_NO_VAR7  5
_O_NO_VAR8  6
_O_NO_VAR9  4
_O_NO_VAR10 2
_A_NO_VAR1  3
_A_NO_VAR2  45
_A_NO_VAR3  65
_A_NO_VAR4  3
_A_NO_VAR5  45
_A_NO_VAR6  22
_A_NO_VAR7  12
_A_NO_VAR8  21
_A_NO_VAR9  32
_A_NO_VAR10 11
_D_YES_VAR1 29
_D_YES_VAR2 23
_D_YES_VAR3 23
_D_YES_VAR4 21
_D_YES_VAR5 29
_D_YES_VAR6 23
_D_YES_VAR7 23
_D_YES_VAR8 29
_D_YES_VAR9 21
_D_YES_VAR10    23
```

After

```
_Name_  NUM DENOM                                                                                           
_O_NO_VAR1  2   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR2  4   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR3  3   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR4  5   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR5  6   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR6  4   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR7  5   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR8  6   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR9  4   10                                                                                          
_O_NO_VAR10 2   10                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR1  3   29                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR2  45  23                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR3  65  23                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR4  3   21                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR5  45  29                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR6  22  23                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR7  12  23                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR8  21  29                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR9  32  21                                                                                          
_A_NO_VAR10 11  23                                                                                          
_D_YES_VAR1 29                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR2 23                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR3 23                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR4 21                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR5 29                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR6 23                                                                                          
_D_YES_VAR7 23                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR8 29                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR9 21                                                                                              
_D_YES_VAR1023
```

I Currently have 2 columns Name & NUM and need to create a new column DENOM. The values for *O* has different logic to fill the values for denom that has been taken care, but when I scan through *A* i need to pick the values corresponding to *D* in NUM and fill that for *A* observation in Denom Column from NUM.I need to do this in SAS?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* DATA: */
data have;
input _Name_ : $ 12. NUM;
cards;
_O_NO_VAR1  2
_O_NO_VAR2  4
_O_NO_VAR3  3
_O_NO_VAR4  5
_O_NO_VAR5  6
_O_NO_VAR6  4
_O_NO_VAR7  5
_O_NO_VAR8  6
_O_NO_VAR9  4
_O_NO_VAR10 2
_A_NO_VAR1  3
_A_NO_VAR2  45
_A_NO_VAR3  65
_A_NO_VAR4  3
_A_NO_VAR5  45
_A_NO_VAR6  22
_A_NO_VAR7  12
_A_NO_VAR8  21
_A_NO_VAR9  32
_A_NO_VAR10 11
_D_YES_VAR1 29
_D_YES_VAR2 23
_D_YES_VAR3 23
_D_YES_VAR4 21
_D_YES_VAR5 29
_D_YES_VAR6 23
_D_YES_VAR7 23
_D_YES_VAR8 29
_D_YES_VAR9 21
_D_YES_VAR10 23
;
run;

/* Temporary data from D */
data temp;
  set have;
  where _NAME_ like '_D_YES_%';
  _NAME_ = '_A_NO_' !! scan(_NAME_, -1, "_");
  rename NUM=DENOM;
run;

data want;
  if _N_ = 1 then
    do;
      declare hash H(dataset:"temp");
      H.defineKey('_NAME_');
      H.defineData('DENOM');
      H.defineDone();
    end;

  set have;

  select;
    when (_NAME_ =: '_O_NO_')
      do;
        /* logic for O */
        DENOM = 10;  
      end;
    when(_NAME_ =: '_A_NO_')
      do;
        /* Logic for A */
        DENOM = .;  
        _N_=H.find();
      end;
    otherwise DENOM = .;
  end;

run;
proc print;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%let pgm=utl-partial-sql-join-based-on-a-column-value-in-wps-sas-r-and-python;

Partial sql join based on a column value in wps sas r and python

github

https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-partial-sql-join-based-on-a-column-value-in-wps-sas-r-and-python

I added SQL solutions for R, python, and wps.

Stackoverflow/SAS

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971683/a-logic-to-pick-the-values-in-num-to-fill-for-denom-from-2-columns

  1 wps/sas sql
  2 R sql
  3 Python sql

/*                   _
(_)_ __  _ __  _   _| |_
| | `_ \| `_ \| | | | __|
| | | | | |_) | |_| | |_
|_|_| |_| .__/ \__,_|\__|
        |_|
*/

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
options validvarname=upcase;

/*----  No need to split _NAME_. It just eliminatea subsequent spliting  ----*/
/*----  Much less messy sql processing                                   ----*/
/*----  I have removed columns that do not change from input to output   ----*/

data sd1.have(drop=_name_ yn var);
retain ltr varnum num;
input _Name_ : $ 12. NUM;
ltr=scan(_name_,1,'_');
yn =scan(_name_,2,'_');
var=scan(_name_,3,'_');
varnum=input(substr(var,4),best.);
cards4;
_O_NO_VAR1  2
_O_NO_VAR2  4
_O_NO_VAR3  3
_O_NO_VAR4  5
_O_NO_VAR5  6
_O_NO_VAR6  4
_O_NO_VAR7  5
_O_NO_VAR8  6
_O_NO_VAR9  4
_O_NO_VAR10 2
_A_NO_VAR1  3
_A_NO_VAR2  45
_A_NO_VAR3  65
_A_NO_VAR4  3
_A_NO_VAR5  45
_A_NO_VAR6  22
_A_NO_VAR7  12
_A_NO_VAR8  21
_A_NO_VAR9  32
_A_NO_VAR10 11
_D_YES_VAR1 29
_D_YES_VAR2 23
_D_YES_VAR3 23
_D_YES_VAR4 21
_D_YES_VAR5 29
_D_YES_VAR6 23
_D_YES_VAR7 23
_D_YES_VAR8 29
_D_YES_VAR9 21
_D_YES_VAR10 23
;;;;;
run;quit;

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                           |                                                                            */
/*                                           |  RULES (create DENOM)                                                      */
/*                                           |                                                                            */
/*  SD1.HAVE total obs=30 17MAY2023:14:52:40 |  DENOM                                                                     */
/*                                           |                                                                            */
/*  Obs    LTR    VARNUM    NUM              |                                                                            */
/*                                           |                                           case l.ltr                       */
/*    1     O        1        2              |  10  Denom hardcode to 10                  when "O" then 10                */
/*    2     O        2        4              |  10                                        when "A" then D.num             */
/*    3     O        3        3              |  10                                       else .                           */
/*    4     O        4        5              |  10                                       end as denom                     */
/*    5     O        5        6              |  10                                                                        */
/*    6     O        6        4              |  10                                                                        */
/*    7     O        7        5              |  10                                                                        */
/*    8     O        8        6              |  10                                                                        */
/*    9     O        9        4              |  10                                                                        */
/*   10     O       10        2              |  10                                                                        */
/*                                           |                                                                            */
/*   11     A        1        3              |  29  Denom use corresponding varnum values in D                            */
/*   12     A        2       45              |  23                                                                        */
/*   13     A        3       65              |  23                                                                        */
/*   14     A        4        3              |  21                                                                        */
/*   15     A        5       45              |  29                                                                        */
/*   16     A        6       22              |  23                                                                        */
/*   17     A        7       12              |  23                                                                        */
/*   18     A        8       21              |  29                                                                        */
/*   19     A        9       32              |  21                                                                        */
/*   20     A       10       11              |  23                                                                        */
/*                                           |                                                                            */
/*   21     D        1       29              |   .   Left join nomatch                                                    */
/*   22     D        2       23              |   .                                                                        */
/*   23     D        3       23              |   .                                                                        */
/*   24     D        4       21              |   .                                                                        */
/*   25     D        5       29              |   .                                                                        */
/*   26     D        6       23              |   .                                                                        */
/*   27     D        7       23              |   .                                                                        */
/*   28     D        8       29              |   .                                                                        */
/*   29     D        9       21              |   .                                                                        */
/*   30     D       10       23              |   .                                                                        */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*           _               _
  ___  _   _| |_ _ __  _   _| |_
 / _ \| | | | __| `_ \| | | | __|
| (_) | |_| | |_| |_) | |_| | |_
 \___/ \__,_|\__| .__/ \__,_|\__|
                |_|
*/

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* SD1.WANT total obs=30 17MAY2023:15:08:23                                                                               */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Obs    LTR    VARNUM    NUM    DENOM                                                                                   */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*   1     A        1        3      29                                                                                    */
/*   2     A        2       45      23                                                                                    */
/*   3     A        3       65      23                                                                                    */
/*   4     A        4        3      21                                                                                    */
/*   5     A        5       45      29                                                                                    */
/*   6     A        6       22      23                                                                                    */
/*   7     A        7       12      23                                                                                    */
/*   8     A        8       21      29                                                                                    */
/*   9     A        9       32      21                                                                                    */
/*  10     A       10       11      23                                                                                    */
/*  11     D        1       29       .                                                                                    */
/*  12     D        2       23       .                                                                                    */
/*  13     D        3       23       .                                                                                    */
/*  14     D        4       21       .                                                                                    */
/*  15     D        5       29       .                                                                                    */
/*  16     D        6       23       .                                                                                    */
/*  17     D        7       23       .                                                                                    */
/*  18     D        8       29       .                                                                                    */
/*  19     D        9       21       .                                                                                    */
/*  20     D       10       23       .                                                                                    */
/*  21     O        1        2      10                                                                                    */
/*  22     O        2        4      10                                                                                    */
/*  23     O        3        3      10                                                                                    */
/*  24     O        4        5      10                                                                                    */
/*  25     O        5        6      10                                                                                    */
/*  26     O        6        4      10                                                                                    */
/*  27     O        7        5      10                                                                                    */
/*  28     O        8        6      10                                                                                    */
/*  29     O        9        4      10                                                                                    */
/*  30     O       10        2      10                                                                                    */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/


/*                         __                         _
/ | __      ___ __  ___   / /__  __ _ ___   ___  __ _| |
| | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| / / __|/ _` / __| / __|/ _` | |
| |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \/ /\__ \ (_| \__ \ \__ \ (_| | |
|_|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/_/ |___/\__,_|___/ |___/\__, |_|
             |_|                                   |_|
*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
options validvarname=any;

proc sql;

  create
     table sd1.want as
  select
     l.ltr
    ,l.varnum
    ,l.num
    ,case l.ltr
      when "O" then 10
      when "A" then r.num
     else .
     end as denom
  from
     sd1.have as l left join sd1.have as r
  on
           l.varnum = r.varnum
      and  l.ltr    = "A"
      and  r.ltr    = "D"
  order
      by l.ltr,l.varnum
;quit;

proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;

');

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

/*
 ___  __ _ ___
/ __|/ _` / __|
\__ \ (_| \__ \
|___/\__,_|___/

*/

proc sql;

  create
     table want as
  select
     l.ltr
    ,l.varnum
    ,l.num
    ,case l.ltr
      when "O" then 10
      when "A" then r.num
     else .
     end as denom
  from
     sd1.have as l left join sd1.have as r
  on
           l.varnum = r.varnum
      and  l.ltr    = "A"
      and  r.ltr    = "D"
  order
      by l.ltr,l.varnum
;quit;

/*___                     _
|___ \   _ __   ___  __ _| |
  __) | | `__| / __|/ _` | |
 / __/  | |    \__ \ (_| | |
|_____| |_|    |___/\__, |_|
                       |_|
*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc r;
export data=sd1.have r=have;
submit;
library(sqldf);
want <- sqldf("
  select
     l.ltr
    ,l.varnum
    ,l.num
    ,case l.ltr
      when `O` then 10
      when `A` then r.num
     else NULL
     end as denom
  from
     have as l left join have as r
  on
           l.varnum = r.varnum
      and  l.ltr    = `A`
      and  r.ltr    = `D`
  order
      by l.ltr,l.varnum
");
want;
endsubmit;
import data=sd1.want r=want;
run;quit;
');

proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;

/*____               _   _                             _
|___ /   _ __  _   _| |_| |__   ___  _ __    ___  __ _| |
  |_ \  | `_ \| | | | __| `_ \ / _ \| `_ \  / __|/ _` | |
 ___) | | |_) | |_| | |_| | | | (_) | | | | \__ \ (_| | |
|____/  | .__/ \__, |\__|_| |_|\___/|_| |_| |___/\__, |_|
        |_|    |___/                                |_|
*/


proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc python;
export data=sd1.have python=have;
submit;
 from os import path;
 import pandas as pd;
 import numpy as np;
 import pandas as pd;
 from pandasql import sqldf;
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 from pandasql import PandaSQL;
 pdsql = PandaSQL(persist=True);
 sqlite3conn = next(pdsql.conn.gen).connection.connection;
 sqlite3conn.enable_load_extension(True);
 sqlite3conn.load_extension(`c:/temp/libsqlitefunctions.dll`);
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 want = pdsql("""
  select
     l.ltr
    ,l.varnum
    ,l.num
    ,case trim(l.ltr)
      when `O` then 10
      when `A` then r.num
     else NULL
     end as denom
  from
     have as l left join have as r
  on
           l.varnum = r.varnum
      and  trim(l.ltr)    = `A`
      and  trim(r.ltr)    = `D`
  order
      by l.ltr,l.varnum
    """);
 print(want);
endsubmit;
import data=sd1.want python=want;
run;quit;
');

proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;

/*              _
  ___ _ __   __| |
 / _ \ `_ \ / _` |
|  __/ | | | (_| |
 \___|_| |_|\__,_|

*/
```